# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST after submitting form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

All the get request are working well but when I try to login through form with post request then it's not working and getting "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." error.SSL is also implemented to the site using Let's Encrypt.

Below is login form

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('login-action')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="email"  name="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Email" value="{{old('email')}}" autofocus required />

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Password" required  />

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit" style="background: #F1931B;">login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Route is below

```php
Route::post('/login-action','adminController@login_action')->name('login-action');
```

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` and try again

Comment: Does your `adminController@login_action` function (`public function login_action`) contain any kind of validation? I.e. `$request->validate()`, or similar. On failed validation, and redirect is performed to the `GET` equivalent of `login-action`. Do you have a `Route::get('/login-action', ...)`? What is the route that renders the `<form>` you're using?

Comment: @TimLewis there is no any validation.I made function in web.php file like Route::post('/login-action',function(){
  dd('hello');
}); I still couldnot diedump hello.same error appears.

Comment: @sta offcourse I have already tried all of those.